# Collision Detection for 2D Capsule or Swept Sphere

Tags: c#, raytracing

I am trying to learn how to mathematically define and detect "hits" on a 2D Capsule.

I am defining and detecting hits on a 2D Circle. Here's my class:

```
class Circle
{
    private double xpos;
    private double ypos;
    private double radius;

    public Circle(double x, double y, double r)
    {
        xpos = x;
        ypos = y;
        radius = r;
    }

    public bool HitCircle(double x, double y)
    {
        bool hit = false;

        double distance = Math.Pow(x - xpos, 2) + Math.Pow(y - ypos, 2);         
        if (distance <= radius * radius) hit = true;

        return hit;
    }
}
```

The circle is an x and y position and a radius. The `HitCircle` function is the C# implementation of the distance formula.

A capsule is defined as 4 points and a radius:

```
class Capsule
{
    double x1pos;
    double y1pos;
    double x2pos;
    double y2pos;
    double radius;

    public Capsule(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double r)
    {
        x1pos = x1;
        y1pos = y1;
        x2pos = x2;
        y2pos = y2;
        radius = r;
    }

    public bool HitCapsule(double x, double y)
    {
        bool hit = false;
        //?? This is where I need help
        return hit;
    }
}
```

I need help understanding and implementing the math for the `HitCapsule` function in the capsule class.

As I understand it, a capsule is like a circle, except instead of having a radius around a single point, it has a radius around a line segment.

For now I'm just trying wrap my brain around some of these geometric definitions. I may try my hand at turning this into a simple raytracer in the future but I wanted to get straight to these math parts.

Thanks.

---

I don't know if this is helpful, but here's my 2d "raytracer." It draws the circle to the console using ascii. It's helpful to show me that I've implemented the math correctly.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double aimx = 30;
        double aimy = 8;

        Circle circle = new Circle(45, 13, 12);
        bool hit = circle.HitCircle(aimx, aimy);

        Console.WriteLine("Did we hit? {0}", hit);


        for(int y = 26; y >= 0; y--)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < 90; x++)
            {
                if(x == aimx && y == aimy) //Draw target
                {
                    Console.Write("X");
                }
                else if(circle.HitCircle(x, y)) //Draw all circle hits
                {
                    Console.Write("#");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("-");
                }
            }
            Console.Write('\n');
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point to capsule intersection is a case of calculating the distance of the point to the line segment that defines the capsule. If that's <= r then you intersect.

[There's a question here that shows how to find that distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment), but it does assume a familiarity with vectors and the dot product.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'm reading through it now. Looks like the math gets pretty exciting.

Comment: You ain't seen nothing yet. This is one of the simpler problems in collision

Comment: I was able to get a capsule to work using the link you provided. I am still working through understand the math but it's certainly the correct direction.